# camera parenting with delay

Tags: animation, camera, path

i'm trying to make an animation where we see from the eyes of a pilot of an airplane.

The airplane follow a spline path via follow path, but the inclination/banking is animated by keyframes. The camera is parented to the cockpit (inside the cockpit)
What i like to do, is to find a way to make the camera to move a little, like if the pilot POV suffer from forces/gravity, or with some kind of reverse delay the pilot starts to turn the head a little bit before the airplane turn.

I was wondering if there is a way to do this by using constraints or modifiers or whaterver, so all you need is to animate only the cockpit and the camera is updated if the cockpit animation changes

I tried using the "slow parenting" option, and while it can work this way, it does not offer too much control

Comment: If the plane is following a path, have the pilot (camera) track to a point slightly further along path.

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you need a combination of Drivers (probably with expressions) , Camera Constraints and probably some manual tweaking.

If you brake your animation in sub sequences (as you already described them but in a more meaningful way) you will better understand where and when you should use these techniques I mentioned above.

How to express reversed delay and|or gravity (a proposition):

For instance you already have a procedural animation which is your main animation (follow curve) and then you need additionally some more elegant and automated (procedural) animations. The first one was depended on a "3d object", the next one "pilots suffering" is depending on the first animation so thus for why you would go with a driver, looks more like an equation with two factors, camera direction (curve) and camera speed (tweaking the follow curve completion) by these two you may always know the acceleration (time | speed) so by a third factor you may express it as a simple equation, then it comes to your knowledge of math and your aesthetics to tweak it more.

It may sound a bit complicated but I think that you must try it first and get deeper into drivers and in general procedural and data driven animation.

hope that this was helpful, good luck !